# Freezing first column horizontally and first row both horizontally and vertically

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, freeze

Edit #2: This question is marked as being answered in "Freeze row and columns in Excel (and the same time)", but it is actually not. That question and its answers regard freezing both rows and columns, but only in one direction each. I need to freeze my top row(s) in both directions.

I have the following challenge in Excel 2010: I have a pivot table with several (4) slicers, and want to keep all the slicers and the first column of the pivot table visible at all times.

Using "Freeze panes", it is possible to freeze both the first column and the first row of the worksheet. The problem with this is that with exception of cell A1 (being in the first column), the first row is only frozen with respect to vertical scrolling. If I scroll horizontally, all slicers except one (the one covering cell A1) scrolls out of view.

The setup looks about like this (dummy data obviously, and with just two slicers):

[image]

Scrolling right and downwards, the first column stays visible as desired, and the first row also is visible, but only showing the first slicer:

[image]

How can I keep the slicers always in place?

Edit: One way to rephrase the question is, is it possible to add a completely static (with respects to scrolling) panel to a work sheet?

Comment: I looked at that question before posting, and it is not a duplicate. The question and answer regard freezing both rows and columns, but only in one direction each. I need to freeze my top row(s) in both directions.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/964409/150988) get you what you want (or at least close to it)?

Comment: @Scott : Not exactly, but close enough for now. One drawback with using view -> new window in this case is that the window layout is independent of which worksheet is selected, while I wanted this layout only for one work sheet. So in my case, the filters will be visible no matter which worksheet is selected. It works acceptably, but to consider this question fullysolved, I think changes/additional features would have to be implemented in Excel. (There might be some in Excel 2013, perhaps?). Thanks for the help!

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to reconsider the acceptability of this solution. To make sure the layout will not be changed by accident, I used Protect Workbook Structure and unchecked "show all windows in taskbar" under Options - Advanced - Display. However, with this combination of settings, clicking either "Close all windows" on the taskbar or the upper right X to close the program does nothing. Which would be very confusing to others. Furthermore, the "show all windows" option is not linked to the file, so I can't even make sure every user sees the same as me, or limit the UX change to this file.

Comment: I solved the closing issue by adding the following code to the workbook VBA module: "Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean) \\
\\ ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect \\ End Sub" (\\ denotes line break). This unprotects the workbook when the "Before close" event is activated. I would have liked to avoid using macros/VBA for security and user friendliness reasons, but I guess I'll just have to give up on that. There still remains the issue of making the views appear as only one window without interferring with the behaviour when opening other Excel files...