# Excel - split view of sheet horizontally but viewing two separated sets of columns instead of rows

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have a sheet in excel 2007 which is quite long horizontally. I'd like to see the 'first' columns of the sheet at the same time as the 'last' columns. If I split the sheet horizontally (with a top and bottom windows) it only lets me see two separated sets of rows (like A1 to A10 and A100 to A110). Is there a way to split horizontally but to see A1 to L1 in the top view and M1 to Z1 in the bottom one, for instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying blatantly from [jcbermu's answer](https://superuser.com/a/957147/150988) to [Excel -
Vertical scroll columns A, B, C, D, E but F, G, H stay the same](https://superuser.com/q/957145/150988),

- On the "View" tab, "Window" panel, click on "New Window". 
  This gives you two windows of the same worksheet,
  which you can scroll independently.
- Click the next button over (in the "View" tab, "Window" panel):
  "Arrange All".  In the "Arrange Windows" pop-up, select "Horizontal". 
  (You may also want to check "Windows of active workbook"
  if you have other files open.)

  [image: "Arrange Windows" pop-up]

  This will give you the layout that you want:

[image]

You can scroll the two windows independently horizontally,
which, if I understand you correctly, is what you want. 
You can scroll the two windows independently vertically
(i.e., the windows are not synchronized vertically). 
This might be useful or an inconvenience.